# Simplify conditional table loop without matrix notation in R

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr, lapply

Using the example below, I was wondering if there is a more efficient package or function to do conditional counting and tables on matching string elements--e.g, using the `data.table` package, `dplyr` package, `lapply()` like function?

```
produce = c("apple", "blueberry", "blueberry", "corn",
            "horseradish", "rutabega", "rutabega", "tomato") # Long list

veggies = c("carrot", "corn", "horseradish", "rutabega") # Short list

basket = matrix(rep(0, length(unique(veggies))*length(unique(produce)) ), nrow = length(unique(veggies)),  
                ncol = length(unique(produce)) )

rownames(basket) <- unique(veggies)
colnames(basket) <- unique(produce)

basket
```

Outputs:

```
#               apple blueberry corn horseradish rutabega tomato
# carrot          0         0    0           0        0      0
# corn            0         0    0           0        0      0
# horseradish     0         0    0           0        0      0
# rutabega        0         0    0           0        0      0
```

Finds counts with shared instances

```
for(i in 1:length(veggies)) {

  counter = NULL

  for (j in 1:length(produce)){ 

    if(veggies[i] ==  produce[j]){ 

      basket[i, which( colnames(basket) == produce[j] ) ] <- basket[i, 
                             which( colnames(basket) == produce[j] ) ] + 1

    }

  }

}

basket
```

The result I'm seeking using a faster / more elegant approach:

```
#               apple blueberry corn horseradish rutabega tomato
# carrot          0         0    0           0        0      0
# corn            0         0    1           0        0      0
# horseradish     0         0    0           1        0      0
# rutabega        0         0    0           0        2      0
```

Comment: This may be a [good reference](https://aurelienmadouasse.wordpress.com/2012/05/24/r-code-how-the-to-count-the-number-of-occurrences-of-a-substring-within-a-string/) to the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [data.table](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table)

```
library(data.table)
dcast(data.table(produce), produce~produce)[veggies]

       produce apple blueberry corn horseradish rutabega tomato
#1:      carrot    NA        NA   NA          NA       NA     NA
#2:        corn     0         0    1           0        0      0
#3: horseradish     0         0    0           1        0      0
#4:    rutabega     0         0    0           0        2      0
```

Comment: Quick and much leaner! How do you get around the NAs here?

Comment: `carrot` is not in `produce`. You can replace NAs by 0 as `df[is.na(df)] <- 0`

Comment: Looks like the `dcast()` function is from the `reshape2` package.

Comment: `data.table v1.9.5`(installed from Github) has its own built-in `dcast` function.

Comment: It probably makes more sense to replace `produce <- union(produce,veggies)` before you start. Also, `df[is.na(df)] <- 0` isn't very data.table-ish

Comment: @ExperimenteR Just out of curiosity, do you know if it's simple to reverse the table into two string vectors -- e.g., a reverse `dcast`?

Comment: @Frank I see your point -- eliminates the NA problem. Although, the function I provided would need to be modified for the counts to match.

Comment: @BobHopez maybe `data.table::melt`?

Comment: @Frank Thanks for the pointers. What is the data.table-ish way to replace NAs with 0s?

Comment: All I can think of is `df[,lapply(.SD, function(x)replace(x,is.na(x), 0)),]
` which is a too much fuss.

Comment: @ExperimenteR I don't know the best way to replace the `NA`s after-the-fact. If I really had to do that, then I'd try to work with matrices instead, I think. I just figure if produce is properly defined (as including all veggies -- I mean the OP should have defined it that way, not you in your answer), then you wouldn't hit the `NA`s, right? I think `dcast` & `melt` generally work best if the data is correct before they're used.

Comment: We can avoid NAs by setting `produce <- c(produce, setdiff(veggies, produce))`, but now have to deal with extra columns, which IMHO, is equally bothersome.

Answer (score 2):

The least ugly solution I could think of in base R:

```
newprod <- factor(produce, levels=unique(c(produce,veggies)))
table(newprod,newprod)[veggies,]

#             newprod
#newprod       apple blueberry corn horseradish rutabega tomato carrot
#  carrot          0         0    0           0        0      0      0
#  corn            0         0    1           0        0      0      0
#  horseradish     0         0    0           1        0      0      0
#  rutabega        0         0    0           0        2      0      0
```

Or all in one ugly line:

```
do.call(table, replicate(2,factor(produce, levels=unique(c(produce,veggies))),simplify=FALSE))[veggies,]
```